# Split columns into adjacent columns, use row name as new column name in R

Tags: r, split, transformation

I have a data frame containing two columns of identifying information and one column of letter pairs that are separated by hyphens:

```
df<-data.frame(
    list = rep(1:3, each = 2),
    set =  rep(c("A","B"), times = 3),
    item = c("ab-cd","ef-gh","ij-kl","mn-op","qr-st","uv-wx")  
    )
```

What I have been struggling to accomplish is a transformation of the data frame to the following form, in which: 1. The separate rows indexed by "list" are collapsed into one row each; 2. The "item" column is split into adjacent columns with the hyphen as delimiter; 3. The "set" column serving as the basis for naming the resulting columns.

```
df2 <- data.frame(
       list = c(1:3),
       A_1 = c("ab", "ij", "qr"),
       A_2 = c("cd", "kl", "st"),
       B_1 = c("ef", "mn", "uv"), 
       B_2 = c("gh", "op", "wx"))
```

I've referred to a number of previously posted questions (particularly [here]) and tried to approach the solution step-by-step using the BASE transpose function along with various binding functions, along with the `reshape` package and the `splitstackshape` package. None of my near-solutions are elegant, and I'm wondering if there is a good way of doing this.

As always, I'm incredibly indebted to the community here for advice and feedback.

Comment: Can you show some of your solutions? You're probably almost there!

Comment: Check out the `tidyr` package, e.g. https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: You need dplyr/tidy packages to complete the picture - group_by() in dplyr and spread() in tidyr should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With many thanks to @AnandaMahto: it can be done in one line by first reshaping and then splitting instead of the other way around.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(dcast(as.data.table(df), list ~ set, value.var = "item"), c("A", "B"), "-")
```

We can accomplish in two steps using base R and reshape2.

First, we create columns '1' and '2' containing the split items. Normally, we wouldn't use numerical characters to start a column name with, but it saves us a step in renaming our result columns later.

```
df[,c("1","2")] <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(as.character(df$item),"-"))
```

Then we use `recast`:

```
res <- recast(data=df, list~set+variable, measure.var=c("1","2"))
res

  list A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2
1    1  ab  cd  ef  gh
2    2  ij  kl  mn  op
3    3  qr  st  uv  wx
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't post examples of my failed solutions in time, but this this a helpful reply. Thanks very much @Heroka

Comment: I would have done `cSplit(dcast(as.data.table(df), list ~ set, value.var = "item"), c("A", "B"), "-")`....

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks so much! I've added it to the answer, hope that's OK with you (and removed my two-step splitstackshape-solution).

Comment: No problem. Glad to help out :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto and Heroka... you're the dream team I needed today! THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, this also works nicely within the Hadleyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate(item, 1:2) %>% 
  gather(val, item, -set, -list) %>% 
  mutate(set=paste(set, val, sep="_")) %>% 
  select(-val) %>% 
  spread(set, item)
#   list A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2
# 1    1  ab  cd  ef  gh
# 2    2  ij  kl  mn  op
# 3    3  qr  st  uv  wx
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, this also works nicely with the base R nemesis of the Hadleyverse, `reshape`:

```
reshape(cbind(df[-3], 
              do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$item), "-"))), 
        direction = "wide", idvar = "list", timevar = "set")
#   list 1.A 2.A 1.B 2.B
# 1    1  ab  cd  ef  gh
# 3    2  ij  kl  mn  op
# 5    3  qr  st  uv  wx
```

(But `dcast` + `cSplit` would be much more efficient and readable).